# Mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 2014 (HY000): Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, angular, mysql-connector, internal-server-error

So I'm building an web-app using ANGULAR8, Python and MYSQL.
All my http requests work when I use Postman, however when I reload my client I get InternalServerError500 some of the times since I make multiple http request simultaneously.

Those are the errors given when I make different requests using my client:

[image: screenshot]

In the python console the message given is this:

[image: screenshot]

**This is my Repository:**

````
from viacord.main.configuration.Configuration import dbConection
from viacord.main.models.SampleInfo import SampleInfo


sample_info_repository = Blueprint('sample_info_repository', __name__, template_folder='templates')


class SampleInfoRepository:
    def __init__(self):
        self = self


# GET ALL - SAMPLE INFO
    @staticmethod
    def getAllSampleInfo():
        cursor = dbConection.cursor()
        sample_info_list = []
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM viacord.sampleinfo")
        mycursor = cursor.fetchall()
        if mycursor is None:
            return "No data found."
        else:
            for row in mycursor:
                sample_info = SampleInfo(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4])
                sample_info_list.append(sample_info)
            return sample_info_list

# GET SAMPLE BY ID
    @staticmethod
    def getSampleByID(id):
        cursor = dbConection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM viacord.sampleinfo WHERE id = %s", [id])
        mycursor = cursor.fetchone()
        if mycursor is None:
            return "No data found."
        else:
            return SampleInfo(mycursor[0], mycursor[1], mycursor[2], mycursor[3], mycursor[4])

# GET SAMPLE BY SAMPLE ID
    @staticmethod
    def getSampleBySampleID(sampleId):
        cursor = dbConection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM viacord.sampleinfo WHERE sampleId = %s", [sampleId])
        mycursor = cursor.fetchone()
        if mycursor is None:
            return "No data found."
        else:
            return SampleInfo(mycursor[0], mycursor[1], mycursor[2], mycursor[3], mycursor[4])```
````

**This is my Controller:**

```
from flask import Blueprint
from viacord.main.repositories.SampleInfoRepository import SampleInfoRepository

# BLUEPRINT (sample_info_controller)
sample_info_controller = Blueprint('sample_info_controller', __name__, template_folder='templates')

# APPLICATION ROUTES


# SAMPLE INFORMATION - GET ALL
@sample_info_controller.route('/sampleinfo/getall', methods=['GET'])
def getAllSampleInfo():
    return json.dumps(SampleInfoRepository.getAllSampleInfo(), default=lambda x: x.__dict__)


# SAMPLE INFORMATION - GET BY ID
@sample_info_controller.route('/sampleinfo/get/id/<id>', methods=['GET'])
def getProcessedSampleById(id):
    return json.dumps(SampleInfoRepository.getSampleBySampleID(id), default=lambda x: x.__dict__)


# SAMPLE INFORMATION - GET BY ID
@sample_info_controller.route('/sampleinfo/get/id/<id>', methods=['GET'])
def getSampleInformationById(id):
    return "I'm returning the sample with the following id:" + id


# SAMPLE INFORMATION - GET BY SAMPLE ID
@sample_info_controller.route('/sampleinfo/get/sampleid/<sampleId>', methods=['GET'])
def getSampleInformationBySampleId(sampleId):
    return json.dumps(SampleInfoRepository.getSampleBySampleID(sampleId), default=lambda x: x.__dict__)
```

**This is my angular service:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpHeaders, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { SampleInfo } from '../models/sample-info';


const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SampleInfoService {

private sampleUrl: string;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    this.sampleUrl =  'http://localhost:5000/sampleinfo';
  }

  public findById(id: number) {
    return this.httpClient.get<SampleInfo>(this.sampleUrl.concat('/get/') + id);
  }

  public findAll() {
    return this.httpClient.get<SampleInfo[]>(this.sampleUrl.concat('/getall'));
  }

  public findSampleBySampleId(sampleId) {
    return this.httpClient.get<SampleInfo>(this.sampleUrl.concat('/get/sampleid/' + sampleId))
  }

  public findByDate(date: String) {
    return this.httpClient.get<SampleInfo[]>(this.sampleUrl.concat('/getbydate/' + date)); 
  }

  public newSample (sample: SampleInfo) {
    return this.httpClient.post<SampleInfo>(this.sampleUrl.concat('/add'), JSON.stringify(sample), httpOptions);
  }

  public deleteById (number: Number) {
  return this.httpClient.delete(this.sampleUrl.concat('/delete/' + number));  
  }

  public deleteAll () {
    return this.httpClient.delete(this.sampleUrl.concat('/deleteall'));
  }
}
```

**This is the component where I call my Angular Service**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { SampleInfoService} from '../../services/sampleinfo.service'
import { SampleInfo } from 'src/app/models/sample-info';
import { ProcessedSamplesService } from 'src/app/services/processedsamples.service';
import { ProcessedSample } from 'src/app/models/processed-sample';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-sample-tab',
  templateUrl: './add-sample-tab.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-sample-tab.component.css']
})
@Injectable()
export class AddSampleTabComponent implements OnInit {

// Variables used in the NG MODEL - By default we assume that the user doesn't know the initial weight
currentDate = this.datepipe.transform(Date.now(), 'MM-dd-yyyy');
choosenDate = this.currentDate;
sampleID = '';
temperatureOrigin = 'NA'
temperatureDestination = 'NA'
isInitialWeightKnown = 'false';
initialWeight: number = 0;
comments = '';

// Variables used to retrieve the information from the Services
mySampleInfoList = [];
mySampleInfo : SampleInfo;
myProcessedSampleId;

// Variables used to provided dinamic messages to help the user fill the form
sampleIdIsNotValid = '';
initialWeightIsNotValid = 'none';
sampleWasAdded = 'none';
sampleWasNotAdded = 'none';
sampleWasAlreadyProcessed = 'none';


constructor(public datepipe: DatePipe, public sampleInfoService: SampleInfoService, public processedSamplesService: ProcessedSamplesService, public router: Router) { }

ngOnInit() {

}

ngAfterViewInit() {
this.getAllSampleInfo()
}

// Get all my Sample Information
getAllSampleInfo(){
  this.sampleInfoService.findAll().subscribe(allSampleInformation => {
    allSampleInformation.forEach(sampleInfo => {
        this.mySampleInfoList.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(sampleInfo)))
      })
  })
}

// Get my selected sample by SAMPLEID
selectSampleId() {
  console.log("My sample id is: ", this.sampleID)
  this.sampleInfoService.findSampleBySampleId(this.sampleID).subscribe(sample => {
    this.mySampleInfo = sample;
    this.temperatureOrigin = sample.temperatureOrigin;
    this.temperatureDestination = sample.temperatureDestination;
  })
  // SEARCH 
  this.processedSamplesService.findBySampleId(this.sampleID).subscribe(processedSample => {
    this.myProcessedSampleId = processedSample.id;
  })
}


sendMyValidatedSampleInformation() {
  // Calculating the volume
  let bufferVolume;
  this.processedSamplesService.calculateBufferVolume(this.initialWeight).subscribe(calculatedBufferVolume => bufferVolume = calculatedBufferVolume)
  let myProcessedSample = new ProcessedSample(0,this.mySampleInfo.sampleId,this.isInitialWeightKnown,this.initialWeight, 
    this.datepipe.transform(this.choosenDate, 'MM-dd-yyyy'),this.comments, bufferVolume);

  // Sending the Request
  this.processedSamplesService.newSample(myProcessedSample).subscribe(submitNewSample => console.log(submitNewSample))
  console.log("DATE " + this.datepipe.transform(this.choosenDate, 'MM-dd-yyyy') + "| SAMPLE ID:" + this.sampleID + "| WEIGHT: " + this.initialWeight + " | COMMENTS: " + this.comments );

}
}
```

Comment: Are you running multiple SQL commands in a single `cursor.execute()` call ?

Comment: I only execute one query for each one. Actually each method/request only executes one command.

Comment: Solved! I had to open a dbConection for each method and close it.